# Default move constructor behavior with std::string attributes

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple data class in which I want to save some typing and let the compiler generate the move constructor and assignment operator:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(int x, std::string&& y) : x_(x), y_(std::move(y)) {}
  A(A && a) = default;
  A& operator= (A && a) = default;
private:
  int x_;
  std::string y_;
};
```

Assuming my compiler is 100% C++11 compliant, will it do the right thing with the `std::string y_` attribute? Will it apply move semantics to it?

Comment: If your compiler conforms to the C++ standard, then it will do what the standard requires. So generally you shouldn't be worrying about what your compiler does; just follow the language rules.

Comment: (Note that your class now has a deleted copy constructor ([demo](http://ideone.com/02sbMw)). It's best not to declare anything explicitly whose implicit definition already provides what you need.)

Comment: Why do you think it would not?  `std::string` is movable.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Because, to be fair, this whole feature of C++ is not exactly expressive. There are surprising considerations everywhere. That `std::move` doesn't actually move anything is just one of them. I think it's fair to ask and check!

Comment: @KerrekSB it is in fact my intention that the copy constuctor is deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule, from [class.copy], is:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class `X` performs a memberwise copy/move
>   of its bases and members.

So in this case, it will move-construct/assign both `x_` and `y_`. from the `A` that you're move-construct/assigning from.

---

Note that a defaulted move constructor can *still perform copies* if one of its members has the move constructor not implicitly defined:

```
struct A {
    A() { }
    A(A const& ) { }
    // A(A&& ) not implicitly defined because of the copy ctor
};

struct B {
    B() = default;
    B(B&& ) = default;
    B& operator=(B&& ) = default;

    A a;
};

B b;
B c = std::move(b); // copy-constructs c.a from b.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will, that's the whole point of generating special member functions.

However, you forgot to move the parameter of the constructor into the member:

```
A(int x, std::string&& y) : x_(x), y_(std::move(y)) {}
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ ^
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot that while writing a simplified test case. Question updated